# Html Code converter from emacs

Tags: html, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I want to post syntax highlighted code on my blog but I can't find any online service 
that would do that for me so I thought I could hook it up using [pygments](http://pygments.org/)

Anyone knows how to hook it up from an emacs buffer ?

I need to invoke something like [these examples](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/) but from command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend the use of [htmlize](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) in this case.  Pygments is nice, but if you have Emacs set up with [color themes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) and have a mode that already knows how to syntax highlight your code, htmlize will leverage that and take give you HTML that looks just like your Emacs buffer.

If you have a light background in your blog, try `color-theme-high-contrast` or `color-theme-blipp-blopp`.  If it is dark, try `color-theme-taming-mr-arneson` or `color-theme-comidia`.  Those are my personal favorites.

Comment: +1 for htmlize.el. Especially when you integrate it with org-mode and the `#+BEGIN_CODE` blocks